# jQuery remove all elements until id='whatever' found

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to remove all the code from the start tag  to the next

I've tried this

```
$('#page1').remove();
```

But that only removes what's between the  tag.

And I don't know what else could be between the page1 and page2 tags as the code is dynamically added based on the types of form elements on the page

```
<div id='page1' name='page1'>
 ...
</div> 
<div id='another element' />
<div id=yet 'another element' />
...
<!-- Need to remove from page1 to here -->
<div id='page2' name='page2'>
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: in the above example: you want to remove page1, another element, yet another element ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove `page1` and everything until `page2` you can do this:

```
$("#page1").nextUntil("#page2").andSelf().remove();
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/PCLvK/1/)**

Comment: wow, I never knew about nextUntil and andSelf methods. Surely this is the simplest.

Comment: Absolutely amazing.  I'm going to find a way to use these just to use them!

Answer (score 0):

If they are nested (?) and you want to delete the children in the 'page1' div, you could do something like this maybe:

```
$('#page1' > div).remove();
```

Or, if you wanted to selectively do it - and only delete certain divs in the page 1 - you could add a class it it and do the same type of thing.

Comment: Did you mean `$('#page1 > div').remove();`?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
var last = null;
var curr = $('#page1');
while (curr.attr('id') != 'page2') {
    if (last != null) {
        last.remove();
    }
    last = curr;
    curr = curr.next();
}
if (last != null) {
    last.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="#another"]:not([id^="#page"])').each(function()
{
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Removes all the elements that start with `another` but excludes elements that starts with `page`.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to transend "ID" in JQuery it is easy to use "class" instead. To each tag that might form a *set of controls to be removed* add  class="removeSet1". Then when needed you invoke `$(".revoveSet1").remove();`